# ReWriting URL for Linking to the page

Tags: php, .htaccess, social-networking

Almost everyone has gone to Facebook. On Facebook they have a url like `www.facebook.com/username`
but on a site that has their user structure like this: `site.com/profile.php?user=username` how can you rewrite the link to look like Facebook (ie: `site.com/username`) so that if you go to `site.com/username` in your browser, it will actually link to the `site.com/profile.php?user=username` without only looking like it is rewriting the URL while you are on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /profile\.php\?username=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2\? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```